# Disable dates further than 2 days from current date in Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jQuery UI DatePicker. I want to disable dates after 2 days from current date. How can I do that?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is a trivial thing that is fully explained in the documentation ... did you not read that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `maxDate` property. Providing `+2` will give a value 2 days from the current. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    maxDate: '+2'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    maxDate: '+2'
  });
});
```